# What is the point of using git alias?

Tags: git, shell, alias

Consider the following:

```
$ git config --global alias.show-graph 'log --graph --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline'
```

Now, typing `git show-graph` executes the `log` command shown above.

**Question:** Why not just use a bash script for this? Are there any advantages or disadvantages of doing so?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but don't use a bash script, use an alias like `alias gs='git status'`

Answer (score 5):

If you're in the habit of typing `git SOMETHING`, then using git's alias functionality works more conveniently. That's about it.

Answer (score 5):

One possible advantage is that sometimes when you integrate git with other tools, those tools are able to make use of the git aliases.

For example the [fugitive plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) for vim allows you to execute arbitrary git commands using `:Git <command>` - so you can use git aliases - you wouldn't be able to use a standard alias or bash script within the same context.

Answer (score 1):

Some people version their *dotfiles* to use them across multiple systems. Then you'll have access to the git aliases everywhere you deployed your favorite `~/.gitconfig`

The same goes for bash aliases in favor of bash scripts. But I'd rather use `git alias` than `alias` and thus keep git related configuration separate in `.gitconfig`.